# Find max and min date from different property

Tags: c#, linq

Here I'm finding `max` and `min` from dates, It should consider both `StartDate` and `EndDate` and get `max` and `min` date from it. See the below code, Is there any better way of doing this using LINQ.

```
public partial class Process
{
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processes = new List<Process>();

        var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        var month = DateTime.Now.Month;

        processes.Add(new Process() { StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1),
                                      EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 22) });
        processes.Add(new Process() { StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 14),
                                      EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 23) });
        processes.Add(new Process() { StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 19),
                                      EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 31) });
        processes.Add(new Process() { StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 27),
                                      EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 12) });
        processes.Add(new Process() { StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 30),
                                      EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 2) });

        var smax = processes.Max(p => p.StartDate) ;
        var emax = processes.Max(p => p.EndDate);

        var smin = processes.Min(p => p.StartDate);
        var emin = processes.Min(p => p.EndDate);

        var max = smax > emax ? smax : emax;
        var min = smin < emin ? smin : emin;

    }
```

Comment: Try `Math.Min` and `Math.Max`, this doesn't handle `DateTime` though. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.min(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It is not a good idea to use class names used by the framework, such as `Process`. It may be okay now, but likely to come back to bite you.

Comment: I think you need something more than just max min, like an extension to find if dates overlap , if dates are valid (eg startdate less tan endate etc ) then get max in single linq. you can get some idea from [[link(]http://blog.reneorban.com/2013/01/generic-method-to-check-if-dates-or.html)]([link(]http://blog.reneorban.com/2013/01/generic-method-to-check-if-dates-or.html)) and just right your own min max on top of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any better way of doing this using linq?

Yes. Like this:

```
var max = processes.Max(p => p.StartDate > p.EndDate ? p.StartDate : p.EndDate);
var min = processes.Min(p => p.StartDate < p.EndDate ? p.StartDate : p.EndDate);
```

Comment: Will this handle Null

Comment: @ManiothShijith Did your code handle Null? You just asked *Is there any better way of doing this using linq* and I suggested one solution.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need of using linq for this purpose. The following

```
var max = smax > emax ? smax : emax;
```

can be written also as:

```
var max = new DateTime(Math.Max(smax.Ticks, emax.Ticks)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. If we ignore the possibility of negative time then any given start date is smaller or equal to the corresponding end date. This means that min will be the smallest start date and max will be the highest end date.

You do not need LINQ to determine them:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processes = new List<Process>();

        var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        var month = DateTime.Now.Month;

        var myFirstDate = new Process() { StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 22) };
        processes.Add(myFirstDate);
        processes.Add(new Process() { StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 14), EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 23) });
        processes.Add(new Process() { StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 19), EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 31) });
        processes.Add(new Process() { StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 27), EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 12) });
        var myLastDate = new Process() { StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 30), EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 2) };
        processes.Add(myLastDate);

        var max = myLastDate.EndDate;
        var min = myFirstDate.StartDate;

    }
```

Comment: The order can change, It will be dynamic.

Comment: @ManiothShijith in that case you can select the smallest StartDate as minimum and the greatest EndDate as maximum.

Comment: The dates may overlap. It can Endtime of one record may be less than start time of next record.

Comment: @ManiothShijith true, but the biggest EndDate should be bigger than the biggest StartDate and the smallest StartDate should be smaller than the smallest EndDate.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a list of all dates, sort them and get the first and the last:

```
var dates = processes.Select(p=>p.StartDate).Concat(from p in processes let d= p.EndDate where d.HasValue select d.Value).OrderBy(d=>d).ToList();       
DateTime min = dates[0], max = dates[dates.Count - 1];
```

The ToList is optional, min and max can be used directly, but this way the ordering is only done once.

side note, since EndDate is nullable, the empty enddates are filtered out first.